# Regex: match string between two strings within an Excel Visiual Basic application (VBA) function (marco, module). (regular expression)

Tags: regex, vba, function, module

I do have this wonderful regular expression: `(?<=, )(.*)(?= \()`, which matches any characters between "," and "(".

For eg. from the following string it matches the highlighted text: "Hey man, `my regex is Super (Mega) Cool` (SC)". I tested in various regex testers (e.g. https://extendsclass.com/regex-tester.html#ruby).

However, when using it in an Excel VBA Module to create my own function, it does not work (see below).

```
Function extrCountryN(cellRef) As String
    Dim RE As Object, MC As Object, M As Object
    Dim sTemp As Variant
    Const sPat As String = "((?<=, )(.*)(?= \())"      
    
Set RE = CreateObject("vbscript.regexp")
With RE
    .Global = True
    .MultiLine = True
    .Pattern = sPat
    If .Test(cellRef) Then
        Set MC = .Execute(cellRef)
        For Each M In MC
            sTemp = sTemp & ", " & M.SubMatches(0)
        Next M
    End If
End With

extrCountryN = Mid(sTemp, 3)

End Function

'https://extendsclass.com/regex-tester.html
```

Trying similar regex in the same module works perfectly find for me, e.g. `^(.*?)(?= \()` successfully matches everything before the first "(".

How to get it fixed?

Comment: In VBA regex, you can't use lookbehinds. So, just use `,\s*(.*)(?=\s\()`

Comment: Well, probably, you actually want `,\s*(.*?)(?=\s*\()` or `,\s*(.*?)(?=\s+\()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As the VBA regex engine does not support lookbehind assertions, you can remove it and use a consuming pattern instead. It is simple in this case because you are actually only using the captured value (with `M.SubMatches(0)`) in your code.

So, the quick fix is

```js
Const sPat As String = ", (.*)(?= \()"
```

If you need to deal with tabs or spaces, or any whitespace, you need `\s` rather than a literal space:

```js
Const sPat As String = ",\s+(.*)(?=\s\()"
```

See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/ijr9Fc/1).

*Details*:

- `,` - a comma
- `\s+` - one or more whitespaces
- `(.*)` - Group 1: any zero or more chars other than line break chars as many as possible
- `(?=\s\()` - a positive lookahead that matches a location that is immediately followed with a whitespace and `(` char.

See the demo screenshot:

[image]

Comment: it includes the ", " so

Comment: @MsGISRocker It does not matter since the `(...)` create a capturing group and `M.SubMatches(0)` fetches just that.

Comment: @MsGISRocker I added the screenshot proving it does what you need.

Comment: somehow it does not work for me as I'd like. Maybe I simplified my example too much. I extended it here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68349611/vba-regex-extract-multiple-strings-between-strings-within-excel-cell-with-custo

Comment: @MsGISRocker That is a different question. The answer is for the *current* question. For a simplified question, the answer is that simple as I explained.