# regex: match everything, but not a certain multiletter string within VBA Excel function (regular expression, inspite of, anything but, visual basic)

Tags: regex, vba, regex-lookarounds, regex-negation, lookbehind

Folks, here is another on "*regex: match everything, but not ...*", but so far non seems to fit my simple question.

I need to program my Excel function to separate strings from their preceding enumerators (similar as done here: [VBA regex: extract multiple strings between strings within Excel cell with custom function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68349611/vba-regex-extract-multiple-strings-between-strings-within-excel-cell-with-custo))

My first simple string is: "`1 Rome; 2 London; 3 Wembley Stadium`"

My second string looks like: "`1.1 Winner; 2.1 Looser; 3.3 Penalties (always loose, dam)`"

And I need to extract only the names but not the ranks ( eg. "`Rome; London; Wembley Stadium`" and  "`Winner; Looser; Penalties (always loose, dam)`").

Using a regex tester (https://extendsclass.com/regex-tester.html), I can simply match the opposite by:

`([0-9]+\s*)` and it gives me:

"`1` Rome, `2` London, `3` Wembley Stadium".

But how to reverse it? I tried something like:

`[^0-9 |;]+[^0-9 |;]`, but it also excludes white spaces that I want to maintain (e.g. after the comma and in between Wembley and Stadium, ... "1 `Rome,` 2 `London,` 3 `Wembley` `Stadium`"). I guess the "`0-9` " needs be determined somehow as **one continuous** string. I tried various brackets, quotation marks, `\s*`, but nothing jet.

**Note: I'm working in a visual basic environment and not allowing lookbehinds!**
**Note: My solutions needs to be compatible across Excel versions as far as possible!**

Comment: If you want to end up with a list of individual names then splitting on `;` & looping removing leading spaces/digits would be a simple way. If you want the names in a single string together then just match the digit part `(\d*(\.?\d+)\s+)` and RegEx.Replace it with `""`.

Comment: You should simply add `(?:\.\d+)*` to match zero or more occurrences of a `.` and one or more digits, `\d+(?:\.\d+)*\s*(.*?)(?=;\s*\d+(?:\.\d+)*\s|$)`

Comment: Did this solution solve the problem?

Comment: @Wiktor: Somehow it does not, even though it reads logical to me. It includes also the numerical prefix in my VBA function. No idea why.

Comment: Again, use `match.Submatches(0)` only. Of course the number will land in the whole match.

Answer (score 1):

I tried negating the numerical values and the period as "one continuous string" `([^\d|\.])`. This will keep two spaces at some places.
[image: Test regex 1]

The explaination group by group [regexr](https://regexr.com/)
[image: Explaination]

To remove these double spaces try with `([^\d|\.])(?<!; )` Here I'm just adding a negative look behind which might not be supported by all regex interpreters.

[image: test regex 2]

[image: Negative lookbehind explanation and warning]